# what's the mechanism of sizeof() in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

It seems sizeof is not a real function?

for example, if you write like this:

```
int i=0;
printf("%d\n", sizeof(++i));
printf("%d\n", i);
```

You may get output like:

```
4
0
```

And when you dig into the assemble code, you'll find sth like this:

```
movl     $4, %esi
leaq     LC0(%rip), %rdi
xorl %eax, %eax
call     _printf
```

So, the compiler put directly the constant "4" as parameters of printf add call it. Then what does sizeof do?

Comment: Note that the expression passed to sizeof is not evaluated, so i does *not* pre-increment.  Looks like a lovely way to introduce a bug into (or obfuscate) some code.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You know, there's a reason why there are [standard documents (3.8MB PDF)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf); C99, section 6.5.3.4, §2:

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size
>   (in bytes) of its operand, which may
>   be an expression or the parenthesized
>   name of a type. The size is determined
>   from the type of the operand. The
>   result is an integer. If the type of
>   the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated;
>   otherwise, **the operand is not
>   evaluated and the result is an integer
>   constant**.

---

In response to ibread's comment, here's an example for the C99 variable length array case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t sizeof_int_vla(size_t count)
{
    int foo[count];
    return sizeof foo;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%u", (unsigned)sizeof_int_vla(3));
}
```

The size of `foo` is no longer known at compile-time and has to be determined at run-time. The generated assembly looks quite weird, so don't ask me about implementation details...

Comment: There's also a reason why stackoverflow.com exists.

Comment: @jalf: "Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.  Unless he doesn't like sushi—then you also have to teach him to cook." - or something ;)

Comment: So, is there an example to show that "variable length array type" case?

Comment: Perhaps not immediately obvious from the above snippet, any function call or side effect in a sizeof that takes the size of a VMT (variably modified type), as is the type of a VLA, causes the side effect to happen if it's important for determining the value: `int gimme(void) { format("C:/"); return 2; } int main(void) { sizeof(int[gimme()]); }`. This will actually format :) Conversely, whether the following will format is unspecified: `sizeof((int(*)[format()])0)`: changing the value of `format()` will not change the result of sizeof (for impls where all object pointers have the same size).

Answer (score 17):

`sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

It's *usually* evaluated as compile time - the exception being when it's used on C99-style variable length arrays.

Your example is evaluating `sizeof(int)`, which is of course known at compile time, so the code is replaced with a constant and therefore the `++` doesn't exist at run-time to be executed.

```
int i=0;
cout << sizeof(++i) << endl;
cout << i << endl;
```

It's also worth noting that since it's an operator, it can be used without the brackets on values:

```
int myVal;
cout << sizeof myVal << endl;
cout << sizeof(myVal) << endl;
```

Are equivalent.

Comment: there's a small error: `sizeof int` is not valid C as types have to be parenthesised!

Answer (score 8):

Sizeof analyzes the passed expression to find its type. It then returns the size of the type.

Because the size of a type is always known at compile time, it is put into the machine code as a constant.

Comment: +1 in C++, and pre C99. In C99, the size of a type is not always known at compile time: `void f( int N ) { int array[N]; printf( "%d\n", sizeof(array) ); }`. In this case, the size of the array is not known at compile time but at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

It is replaced with the constant (4 in your case) at compile time. Because it takes 4 bytes to hold an int on your platform.

And your code will  not compile, instead of giving you any output ;-) Because of `sizoef` ;-)

Comment: BTW, it depends on the implementation, but I doubt most of them will produce call to `_printf` when doing `operator<<` for cout.

Answer (score 1):

The size of returned type is calculated at compile time, there is no runtime overhead

Answer (score 1):

In C++ `sizeof()` calculates size of the type of the *expression* within it and replaces the whole "`sizeof()` function call" with a constant during compilation.

The expression within `sizeof()` is never evaluated during the program execution.  And it may not even be a type name.  Check these examples out:

```
struct X { int i; double j;};
int call_to_undefined_function();

sizeof(10/0);
sizeof( ((struct X*)NULL)->j );
sizeof( call_to_undefined_function() + 100 );
sizeof( call_to_undefined_function() + 100.0 );
sizeof( double() / int() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what it's meant to do: puts directly the constant "the size of the variable/constant/type/etc" into the code

Answer (score 0):

sizeof() returns the size in bytes of whatever you pass as an argument to it.
In a 32-bit architecture sizeof(int) would return 4, while sizeof(char) would return 1.

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself: 'sizeof' is not a function. It is a built-in operator with special syntax and semantics (see the previous responses). To remember better that it is not a function, you might want to get rid of the habit to use superfluous braces and prefer to use the "braceless" 'sizeof' with expressions as in the following example

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof ++i);
```

This is exactly equivalent to your original version.