# C++ static arrays and sizeof operator

Tags: c++, arrays, static, sizeof

As I know `sizeof` is compile time operator, so why does this code compile and run correctly without any warnings?

```
#include <iostream>

    int main() {    
        int size;
        std::cin >> size;
        int array[size];
        std::cout << sizeof(array) / sizeof(int) << std::endl;
    }



g++ -v
Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-java-awt=gtk --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-9)
```

Comment: What do you expect it to say?

Comment: Does this code compile and run perfectly? Which compiler you are using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the mechanism of sizeof() in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581839/whats-the-mechanism-of-sizeof-in-c-c)

Comment: @bash.d Ok this is not valid c++ code, why no warnings?

Comment: @Subhajit see updated version

Comment: What compiler are you using? Did you set it to display ALL warnings?

Comment: I complied without any options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the code is not valid C++ since there are no [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLAs) in C++. They are a C feature. Your C++ compiler supports them as a non-standard extension. Use `-Wvla` or `-pedantic` to get a warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'array' [-Wvla]
```

Secondly, the `sizeof()` operator is no longer a compile-time construct when applied to C VLAs. The C standard hints at this in **§6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` operator**:

> If the type of the operand is a variable length array
>   type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an
>   integer constant.